# Load portion of the data from Model in MVC with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to make a gallery page of sort, that get's a 1000 random pictures and passes it onto the view. As you would imagine loading a 1000 pictures at once on the page slows the view down quite a bit.

Is there a way to divide up the model received from the controller into like 200 image pieces that load as the page scrolls or only after the first 200 is loaded?

Controller code I have so far

```
Random r = new Random();
List<GalleryViewModel> gallery = new List<GalleryViewModel>(images.Count);
gallery.AddRange(images);
gallery = gallery.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).Take(1000).ToList();
return View(gallery);
```

I am not quite sure on how to go about dividing up the 1000 with Javascript at all. So, im lacking in that code as of now. Sorry for that!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There's a plugin called jQuery who I think will help you. It will download the image only when it receives the browser focus. Take a look http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/

Comment: I'll check it out and see how I can fit it into the MVC concept! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Another option is create JSON action and call it with ajax and append to your gallery, but I think this plugin will solve your problem, I use it in a very long gallery and works very well

Comment: Seems like I keep getting .lazy is not a function error for some reason. Would you perhaps have any idea why that would be?